# Linker error with class that uses a method from a class it extends

Tags: c++, linker

I have some code that compiles, but won't link. I'm not sure why this is - I know that this issue is usually solved by fixing what's linked together, but I don't know why this is breaking. TransGame is a class that extends Game, and SearchGame is a class that extends TransGame.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
mrdmnd@dr-wily:~/ConnectFour$ make all                                                                                                                                                                             
g++    -c -o SearchGame.o SearchGame.cc
g++    -c -o TransGame.o TransGame.cc
g++    -c -o Game.o Game.cc
g++ SearchGame.o TransGame.o Game.o -o SearchGame
TransGame.o: In function `TransGame::hash()':
TransGame.cc:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `Game::positioncode()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [SearchGame] Error 1
```

Here's my makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
SOURCES = SearchGame.cc TransGame.cc Game.cc
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cc=.o)
EXECUTABLE = SearchGame
.PHONY : all clean

all : $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

*.o :
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

Here are the relevant bits of code:

TransGame.cc

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "TransGame.h"
// snip
void TransGame::hash() {
  long htemp = positioncode();
  //snip
}
```

TransGame.h

```
#ifndef TRANSGAME_H
#define TRANSGAME_H
//snip
class TransGame : public Game {
  public:
    //snip
    void hash();
    //snip
};

#endif
```

Game.cc

```
#include "Game.h"
// snip
inline long Game::positioncode() {
  return color[nplies & 1] + color[0] + color[1] + BOTTOM;
}
```

Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
//snip
class Game {
  public:
    //snip
    long positioncode();
    //snip
};

#endif
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm sure I'm missing something obvious in my makefile.

Comment: Lose the inline or move it to the header file with the class definition.

Comment: You can't inline methods that are in the .cc file - they have to be placed in the header file. The reason is that the compiler needs to see the method to inline it, but on usage, he only knows the header file - not the cc file. There might be a compiler that has some kind of dictionary - but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `Game::positioncode()` is an inlined function and needs to be in the header, since the compiler needs to know its definition to replace the call to `positioncode` with the code.

There are two ways: You can either add the function below the definition of `class Game` or you can add it directly to the declaration:

```
class Game {
  public:
    long positioncode()
    {
      return color[nplies & 1] + color[0] + color[1] + BOTTOM;
    }
};
```